# How to disable refreshing background image when clicking in navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a web page the has navbar. If you press on some btn in the navbar the image refreshing and not showing.

i tried to show a pictures when you press on element in navbar. In every btn you can see a different image. i succeed to make the btns and connect them to the JS file.

```js
function changePhotos(e) {
  if (e.target == first) {
    document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage =
      'url("image' + 1 + '.jpg")';
    return;
  }
  if (e.target == sec) {
    document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage =
      'url("image' + 2 + '.jpg")';
    return;
  }
  if (e.targer == third) {
    document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage =
      'url("image' + 3 + '.jpg")';
    return;
  }
}

let first = document.getElementById("pic1");
let sec = document.getElementById("pic2");
let third = document.getElementById("pic3");

first.addEventListener("click", changePhotos);
sec.addEventListener("click", changePhotos);
third.addEventListener("click", changePhotos);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
}

#bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#images {
  position: absolute;
  height: 94%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigate {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 0.1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#images {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>CoOL wEb</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row" id="bar">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="navigate">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Photos</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="" id="pic1">Pic1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="" id="pic2">Pic2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="" id="pic3">Pic3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="images">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

i want that the pictures will stop refreshing and they will be seen.
thanks.

Comment: Remove href=""  or change it to be href="#, add prevent default as well

Comment: I am curious why `'url("image' + 2 + '.jpg");` and not simply `'url("image2.jpg")';`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I'm using it for other question in this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `e.preventDefault();` to the beginning of the `changePhotos` function :

```js
function changePhotos(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (e.target == first) {
    document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage =
      'url("https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content//images/articles/322/322868/golden-retriever-puppy.jpg")';
    return;
  }
  if (e.target == sec) {
    document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage =
      'url("https://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/fashion/daily/2019/06/18/18-puppy-dog-eyes.w700.h700.jpg")';
    return;
  }
  if (e.targer == third) {
    document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage =
      'url("https://tractive.com/static/images/product-images/tratr3g/tractive-gps-3g-dogtracker-dalmatian-dog.jpg")';
    return;
  }
}

let first = document.getElementById("pic1");
let sec = document.getElementById("pic2");
let third = document.getElementById("pic3");

first.addEventListener("click", changePhotos);
sec.addEventListener("click", changePhotos);
third.addEventListener("click", changePhotos);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
}

#bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#images {
  position: absolute;
  height: 94%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigate {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 0.1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#images {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>CoOL wEb</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row" id="bar">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="navigate">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Photos</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="" id="pic1">Pic1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="" id="pic2">Pic2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="" id="pic3">Pic3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="images">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```